# How DiffUtil.DiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this); works internally?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**When dispatchUpdatesTo(this) for DiffUtils.DiffResult (to update list of RecyclerView) is called, on which parameters it decides to call one of the following methods and how it works internally.**

```
 notifyItemInserted(position: Int)
 notifyItemMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int)
 notifyItemRangeInserted(startPosition: Int, itemCount: Int)
 notifyItemRemoved(position: Int)
 notifyItemRangeRemoved(startPosition: Int, itemCount: Int)
 notifyItemChanged(position: Int)
 notifyItemRangeChanged(startPosition: Int, itemCount: Int)
```